# UITableView iOS11 does not scroll - XCode 9

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios11, xcode9

The table view in my app refuses to scroll by user interaction. They are resizable cells depending on image sizes within the cell, so when the table view cell resizes, some of the content scrolls to the right position. But does not scroll at all on user interaction. Please help?

EDIT: The table view does scroll, but only if the user scroll from the left most edge of the screen. No interactions are registers from the centre of the screen until then. There also seems to be some sort of inset on the left, since I noticed a slight gap between the content and the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution to both the scrolling problem and the margin on the left. The table view was scrollable only from the margin since there were no cell contents. This lead me towards delays content touches property.

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = NO;
        self.shoutsFeedTable.delaysContentTouches = YES;
}
```

The property of the viewcontroller `viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins` allows one to set zero margins. This lead to some constraint issues in my project, which were pretty straight forward to fix. Hope this helps anybody else.